# How do I create a new locale, based on an existing locale and a different language?

Tags: locale, language, devuan, antix

I want to create an `en_IL.UTF-8` locale: Languages is English (US English if I need to be specific), but date, number, etc. as is common in Israel/Palestine.

What do I need to do to make this happen?

Note: In case it matters, the distribution is either Devuan Beowulf or antiX 19.3.

Answer (score 1):

**incomplete but functional solution:**

fist check the output of `$ locale`

then read the manuals of these packages and install if suited:

`locale`, `localedef`, `localehelper`, `locales-all`, and `localepurge`

I only installed `locales-all` and set this in my `.bashrc`

```
export LANG="en_GB"
export LANGUAGE="en_GB:en"
export LC_CTYPE="en_GB"
export LC_NUMERIC="de_DE"
export LC_TIME="de_DE"
export LC_COLLATE="de_DE"
export LC_MONETARY="es_MX"
export LC_MESSAGES="en_GB"
export LC_PAPER="de_DE"
export LC_NAME="de_DE"
export LC_ADDRESS="de_DE"
export LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE"
export LC_MEASUREMENT="es_MX"
export LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE"
export LC_ALL=
```

upon next log-in, my sytem was as desired.

with this I have an overhead: unused locales stored in arround `250MiB` (as far as I could extract from `ncdu`). Since Storage is cheap nowadays, I will keep these for now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i needed to do, to create a new locale:

Find a locale that is closest to what is needed, in my case it was `en_US`, now:

```
cd /usr/share/i18n/locales
sudo cp en_US en_XX
sudo vim en_XX
```

Of course, you would not use `en_XX`, for your particular question it would be something like `en_IL`. On Debian there are rather nice comments in the files that make it easy enough to edit them. I also took a peek at the file in my country to get the address strings and paper measurements.

Then it is important to compile that locale:

```
sudo localedef --no-archive -i en_XX  -f UTF-8 en_XX.UTF-8
```

and finally it is possible to actually set it:

```
sudo localectl set-locale en_XX.UTF-8
```